Limit of irreducible (rational) curves is connected
Let $S$ be an algebraic surface, $C\subset S$ an irreducible rational curve. Suppose $\dim |C|\geq 1$ so that we can choose a pencil $\{C_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^1}\subset |C|$ containing $C$. Suppose $C_0 \in \{C_\lambda\}$ is reducible. Then why is $C_0$ connected?
In p.513 of Griffiths-Harris, it is written that "$C_0$ is connected, being the limiting position of irreducible curves $C_\lambda$." I see that by Bertini, a generic element of the pencil $\{C_\lambda\}$ is irreducible, so there are only finitely many reducible curves in the pencil $\{C_\lambda\}$. Thus $C_0$ is in some sense a limit of irreducible curves. But how do we know that it must be connected?
